# How to construct the "lobed Hopf tori"?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, hopf-fibration

I've done the following construction. I expected to get the Clifford torus or another "Hopf torus", such as the ones we can see here: [lobed Hopf tori](http://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/nick/gallery/HopfTorus.html).

Here is my construction. 
First I take the "inverse" Hopf map:
$$
H^{-1}(q,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+q_1)}} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
-(1+q_1)\sin t \\
(1+q_1) \cos t \\
q_2 \cos t + q_3 \sin t \\
-q_2 \sin t + q_3 \cos t
\end{pmatrix}, q \in S^2, t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

I generate all the great circles of $S^2$:
$$
C_{\theta,\phi} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\cos \theta \sin \phi \\
\sin \theta \sin \phi \\
\cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then I calculate the circles of $S^3$ obtained by the inverse Hopf map as follows:
$$
[0, 2\pi] \ni t \mapsto H^{-1}(C_{\theta, \phi}, t)
$$

Finally I apply the stereographic projection to these circles in $\mathbb{R}^4$ in order to map them to $\mathbb{R}^3$. And this is the picture I obtain:

[image]

Here is the same object but drawn in a different way:

[image]

Its not ugly but this does not look like a torus. And I've never seen such a picture elsewhere. What is it?

More importantly, I would like to know how to obtain the *lobed Hopf tori* ([lobed Hopf tori](http://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/nick/gallery/HopfTorus.html)). Is the way to get them close to my construction of am I totally in a wrong way ? In case I'm totally in a wrong way I would appreciate a couple of hints.

Comment: See my blog for an answer : [1/3](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/HopfTorus_1over3.html) [2/3](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/HopfTorus_2over3.html) [3/3](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/HopfTorus_3over3.html). I think there was an error in my $H^{-1}$ formula.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely don't remember how I got the strange shape in my question...

Well, here is how to get a Hopf torus.

The preimage of a point $p=(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ on the unit sphere $S^2$ by the Hopf map is the circle on $S^3$ with parameterization:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathcal{C}_p \colon & (0,2\pi[ & \longrightarrow & S^3 \\
 & \phi & \longmapsto & \mathcal{C}_p(\phi) 
\end{array}
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{C}_p(\phi) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+p_z)}}
\begin{pmatrix}
(1+p_z) \cos(\phi) \\
p_x \sin(\phi) - p_y \cos(\phi) \\
p_x \cos(\phi) + p_y \sin(\phi) \\
(1+p_z) \sin(\phi)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now consider a spherical curve. That is, let $\Gamma$ be a function mapping an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ to the unit sphere $S^2$.
Then the *Hopf cylinder* corresponding to $\Gamma$ has parameterization
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H_\Gamma \colon & I \times (0,2\pi[ & \longrightarrow & S^3 \\
 & (t, \phi) & \longmapsto & \mathcal{C}_{\Gamma(t)}(\phi) 
\end{array}.
$$
When the spherical curve is closed, its corresponding Hopf cylinder is called
a *Hopf torus*. Then we can get a beautiful 3D surface by stereographic projection. A "lobed Hopf torus" as the ones shown [here](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/nick/gallery/HopfTorus.html) is obtained by taking for a sinusoidal-like spherical curve, and the number of lobes corresponds to the number of sinusoidal waves.

For example, consider the [tennis ball curve](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/spherical/index.html), given for a real constant $A$ and an integer constant $n$ by:
$$
\Gamma(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\bigl(\pi/2 - (\pi/2 - A) \cos(nt)\bigr) 
\cos\bigl(t + A \sin(2nt)\bigr) \\ 
\sin\bigl(\pi/2 - (\pi/2 - A) \cos(nt)\bigr) 
\sin\bigl(t + A \sin(2nt)\bigr) \\ 
\cos\bigl(\pi/2 - (\pi/2 - A) \cos(nt)\bigr)
\end{pmatrix}, \quad t \in (0,2\pi[.
$$
Then $\Gamma$ is $(2\pi/n)$-periodic and $n$ corresponds to the number of lobes of the Hopf torus. Here is the result:

[image: Hopf torus tennis ball]

Another example: take the closed curve $\Gamma \colon [0,2\pi] \to S^2$ defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
\Gamma_x \colon t \mapsto \sin\bigl(h\cos(nt)\bigr) \\
\Gamma_y \colon t \mapsto \cos(t)\cos\bigl(h\cos(nt)\bigr) \\
\Gamma_z \colon t \mapsto \sin(t)\cos\bigl(h\cos(nt)\bigr)
\end{cases}
$$
where $h$ is a real number and $n$ is an integer, corresponding to the number of lobes as before.

[image]