# Surface parameterization mapping squares to a "constant shape"

Tags: geometry, surfaces, hopf-fibration

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656795/38217) I explained how a Hopf torus is parameterized. Observe this (stereographically projected) Hopf torus on which I mapped a chessboard:

[image]

This parameterization is not conformal since the squares of the chessboard lose their right angles when mapped. But it seems that all the mapped squares have the same shape (the same angles). Does this property has a name? And is it true?